# Why global variable value is null in adapter class after storing value in android?

Tags: android

I am going to add product while user click on Plus button from UI I have to check condtion if there is cart product data in database or not? and then i have to update or add data as per condition.
I am storing data in global variable after calling api.
problem: while user click on plus button value of global variable is null in Adapter class.so,I am not able to check condition in adapter class.

Comment: make it static variable, i think it should work

Comment: Please add code snippets